# Do you need root access to fully backup a server?

Tags: ssh, backup, sudo, root

I have an account on a server and I would like to automate backups onto another server, I disabled root logins for security. Do you need root access to fully backup a server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally yes, but this might be achieved by `sudo` or a backup daemon as well, it's not mandatory to have `root` login enabled. Details depend on the backup technology you want to use.